# How to create a custom button?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

This is an example of the buttons that I need to create

[image: This]

I want to create a button with the bottom border, I was able to create a button using layer-list, but now for each button I have to create a separate layer-list. Are there any ways to create one template and reuse it?

This is the code to create a button with a layer-list

background_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#793838" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#4056b6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You can use the same drawable for each button. Right?

Comment: this set every button background and text set as center and white color.

Comment: @SibinDavis I can not, I need to create a new drawable each time, because in each drawable I set the color background and bottom border, because of this I think it can create a custom button programmatically. What say?

Comment: @AndroidTeam Oh sure. Can you give advice on how I can implement this more elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Use below link to create custom buttons for android.
http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Comment: A cool idea, but now for each button you have to create a separate XML file. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must do it programmatically, once you have created the layout of a button you can reuse it several times..
here one example but you can find more!
[Creating multiple buttons programmatically: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478444/creating-multiple-buttons-programmatically-android)